# Levi-Civita symbol

Tags: tensor

Is the Levi-Civita symbol a tensor?

R. A. Sharipov afirm (In "Quick Introduction to Tensor Analysis", page 30) that "...the Levi-Civita symbol is NOT a tensor..."

$\epsilon_{jkq}=\epsilon^{jkq}=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}0, & \mbox{if among $j$, $k$, $q$ there are at least two equal numbers} \\ 1 & \mbox{if $(j,k,q)$ is even permutation of numbers $(1,2,3)$} \\ -1 & \mbox{if $(j,k,q)$ is odd permutation of numbers}\end{array}\right.$

What does that phrase mean?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the relevance of $\epsilon_{jkq}$?

Comment: I'm learning about it. In particular, $e_{jkq}$ can be used to write vectorial product (cross product).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Levi-Civita symbol is a "pseudotensor", or [tensor density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_density#Examples), because it inverses sign upon inversion. (An orthogonal transformation with Jacobian $-1$ introduces a minus sign.) As a consequence, the contraction of $\varepsilon_{ijk}$ with two vectors produces a pseudovector, or [axial vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector) -- the cross product.

For a clear discussion see page 11 of these [lecture notes](http://www.physics.ucc.ie/apeer/PY4112/Tensors.pdf) by Asaf Pe'er. In particular, it is explained how to convert the Levi-Civita pseudotensor into a real tensor, at least on orientable manifolds.

Comment: Thanks @Carlo. But I need to understand the words of Sharipov in the context of his article [Sharipov](http://samizdat.mines.edu/tensors/ShR6b.pdf). ¿Does he want to say: "Despite its form or notation will not be a tensor?

Comment: I guess Sharipov wants to distinguish the Levi-Civita _symbol_ from the Levi-Civita pseudotensor (or tensor density). Then he shows how to convert the pseudotensor into a real tensor. See the link to the note I added, where this is worked out in some more detail.

Comment: The lecture notes are very clear! Thank you very much!